# TensorFlow,keras,keras-rlで起こるエラーの対処がわかりません.[TypeError: len is not well defined for symbolic Tensors.]

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, keras, google-colaboratory

Google Colaboratoryで,DQNを行おうと以下のコードを実行しましたが,エラーが出てしまいます.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1, ) + (84,)))
model.add(Dense(128, kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
model.add(Dense(128, kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
model.add(Dense(128, kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='linear'))
print(model.summary())

memory = SequentialMemory(limit=200000, window_length=1)
policy = EpsGreedyQPolicy(eps = 0.1)
dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, nb_actions=3,gamma=0.99, memory=memory, nb_steps_warmup=100,target_model_update=1e-2, policy=policy)
dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
```

以下がエラーの内容です.（モデルの出力は省く）

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-2ed7215a2a6d> in <module>()
      3 
----> 4 dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, nb_actions=3,gamma=0.99, memory=memory,nb_steps_warmup=100,target_model_update=1e-2, policy=policy)
　　　 5 
      6 dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])


/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in __len__(self)
    739     raise TypeError("len is not well defined for symbolic Tensors. ({}) "
    740                     "Please call `x.shape` rather than `len(x)` for "
--> 741                     "shape information.".format(self.name))
    742 
    743   @staticmethod

TypeError: len is not well defined for symbolic Tensors. (dense_4/BiasAdd:0) Please call `x.shape` rather than `len(x)` for shape information.
```

環境はGoogle Colaboratoryを使用しています.

どなたか対処法が分かる方,ご教授お願い致します.
以上

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tensorflow1.X系を使用しているため出ているエラーです。
同様のissueが立っていました。 https://github.com/wau/keras-rl2/issues/4

kerasはtensorflow1系と2系で書き方が違います。
tensorflow 2系をkerasで使用した場合のコードを書いてみましたので参考になれば

```
import tensorflow as tf

from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
from rl.policy import EpsGreedyQPolicy
from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(1, ) + (84,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='linear'))
print(model.summary())

memory = SequentialMemory(limit=200000, window_length=1)
policy = EpsGreedyQPolicy(eps = 0.1)
dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, nb_actions=3,gamma=0.99, memory=memory, nb_steps_warmup=100,target_model_update=1e-2, policy=policy)
dqn.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
```